# Mathematical equivalent to double right shift and AND operator?

Tags: operators, shift

I have to rewrite the following expression in my program code:

```
arr[i] = (arr[i] << 16) & 0x00FF0000;
```

Can I rewrite this with multiplication/division operators ?

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
arr[i] = (arr[i] % 256) * 65536;
```

but bitwise operations are faster

Comment: why do you have % with value 256?

Comment: to emulate bitwise &